# May I use "juxtapose" this way?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

> The bar juxtapose against the beauty parlor.

or

> The beauty parlor is juxtaposed against the bar.

Comment: _The beauty parlor is juxtaposed with the bar._

Comment: You can say "the beauty parlor was adjacent to the bar" (or vice versa), or when drawing a contrast, "the juxtaposition of the saloon and the church was ironic". Note that the key difference is that in the former you're relating one to the other spatially; in the latter you're treating the pair as a unit.

Comment: Anyway,the two examples I wrote makes sense,right? They just have two seperate meaning but not wrong ,right?

Answer (score 2):

Go with the second version.

"Juxtapose" is transitive; it requires a subject - the one acting - and an object - thing being acted on. But logically, it  requires 3 nouns: the one drawing the contrast (note that it's not always stated explicitly), and the 2 items being contrasted.

Your first version has only 2 items, and as written it has the bar doing the juxtaposition, contrasting the beauty parlor against...?

It could be rewritten like so:

> The bar was juxtaposed against the beauty parlor.

The one doing the juxtaposition (the fickle hand of fate?) is implied here. Since "juxtapose" is rarely used, it's difficult to come up with an example that uses it that doesn't sound odd. Here's my best attempt:

> In this painting, I juxtapose the bar against the beauty parlor.

Comment: That's a good attempt, actually. "Juxtapose" is often used in art when you want to state that you've placed two objects in your piece so that it is easy to compare them. So that is just about the sentence I would expect. Like you say, the one performing the juxtaposition is usually implied.